# Unable To Receive remoteControlReceivedWithEvent: (UIEvent*) event

Tags: tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

Am trying to capture play/pause events for AVPlayervIewController native play controls in tvOS. I tried adding UITapgestureRecogniser, presses event but none of them worked. Now am trying to receive the remote control events that also does not work.

I have MyPlayerViewController: UIViewController, which has AVPlayerViewController in it

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.becomeFirstResponder()
        UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
    }

    override func remoteControlReceived(with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let event = event, event.type == UIEvent.EventType.remoteControl {
            if event.subtype == UIEvent.EventSubtype.remoteControlPlay {
                print("received remote play")
            } else if event.subtype == UIEvent.EventSubtype.remoteControlPause {
                print("received remote pause")
            } else if event.subtype == UIEvent.EventSubtype.remoteControlTogglePlayPause {
                print("received toggle")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private var touchSurface: UITapGestureRecognizer!
private var tapGesturePlayPause: UITapGestureRecognizer!
private var tapGestureMenu: UITapGestureRecognizer!

func configure() {
    self.touchSurface = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.yourMethod1))
    self.touchSurface.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(value: UIPressType.select.rawValue)]
    self.addGestureRecognizer(self.touchSurface)

    self.tapGesturePlayPause = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.yourMethod2))
    self.tapGesturePlayPause.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(value: UIPressType.playPause.rawValue)]
    self.addGestureRecognizer(self.tapGesturePlayPause)

    self.tapGestureMenu = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.yourMethod3))
    self.tapGestureMenu.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(value: UIPressType.menu.rawValue)]
    self.addGestureRecognizer(self.tapGestureMenu)
}
```